# What is the recommended way to storage documents as Microservice / API?

Tags: api, api-design, storage, docker, asp.net-core

I'am new in Microservices, and this is the scenario.

Background:
I have an Web Application that  requires store and retrieve files and let's say that i need to storage documents (PDFs, Word Documents, Excel,etc).

My idea is to create an API in .NET core that allows you to create store files and provide an ID so that whoever uses that API can refer to a file after that file ID.

Question: 
The question is, keeping in mind that I will use Docker to run the API as microservice (one or more instances?), Where should my new API, physically save the files so that any type of failure can recover them?.

Some guide would be great.

Comment: Most blog articles will agree that you must approach data storage with a mindset that is different from how you design microservice architecture. Example: ["Store data in databases, not ephemeral service instances."](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-building-a-microservice-architecture) (Note. "Data stores" might be a better phrase.) Microservice instances become stateless, by delegating states to another layer; that later must be designed from ground up for distributed fault tolerance, and also provide some support for persistence and disaster recovery.

Comment: i don't understand why downvote....if  i'm asking, is because is not totally clear for me.

Answer (score 3):

While Docker helps you deploy services, it does not really help you to manage resources. You will have to provide resources for this storage *externally*.

If you will be running your service in some kind of cloud, the cloud provider will likely have a storage product ready to sell to you. Try to estimate how much data in total you will store, and how much you will store/retrieve per day or month *before* you evaluate their pricing.

If you/your organization are running your own servers, there may be very knowledgeable people in a sysadmin role around you who can help you with your storage needs.

The general concepts are that you try to anticipate various problems, and develop solutions to these problems. Depending on your required level of reliability and performance there are a couple of best practices:

- A hard disk may die → use a suitable RAID configuration
- One hard disk is too small → use a suitable RAID configuration
- Cosmic rays may corrupt files before they are written to the filesystem → use ECC memory
- A software error (e.g. in your file system driver) may corrupt your storage → keep multiple disconnected backups
- A fire destroyed your backups → keep off-site backups
- The backups cannot be restored → regularly test your backup procedure by restoring to a spare server
- ...

The hobbyist version of this game is called “build your own NAS”.

Comment: some cloud storage service  (Small??) to recommend ?   (around 4gb or 8gb at max)

Comment: @AlfredSevero No. But at that scale it doesn't really matter. Maybe you don't need to build a cloud computing service, just use a file storage service (cloud like Dropbox or self-hosted like Nextcloud). Or maybe using any database might be better than file-level storage. The above answer is more concerned with terabyte-sized storage arrays.